# ¿Cómo comparar dos objetos genéricos?

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo o entrando al tema de desarrollo guiado por pruebas, y necesito saber cómo se puede comparar dos objetos genéricos.

```
public class Pruebas{
    public static <T> void comparar(T a,T b){
        try{
            if(a>b){
                System.out.println("a es mayor"+a);
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("b es mayor"+b);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("No se puede comparar"+e);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Tendrías que hacer que la clase reciba el tipo también: `public class Pruebas<T>{}`. Y el método ese no tiene mucho sentido... o es tipo `T` o es `void`, no? Te recomiendo revisar primero cómo funcionan los genéricos y luego intentar hacer pruebas con ellos. No puedes hacer pruebas usando genéricos si no sabes usar genéricos, puesto que las pruebas seguramente fallarán y no será porque el código probado esté mal... si no que la prueba está mal! De todas maneras, me parece un poco locura usar una clase genérica entera en un test. Si quieres hacer TDD, busca un buen framework de pruebas!

Comment: Disculpa la ignorancia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede resolver de la siguiente manera.

Como estas comparando valores, estos deben de ser numericos, pero nada te asegura que el usuario ingrese valores numericos.

Usaremos variables globales para asignarle el valor ingresad0.

```
private static Double genericA;
private static Double genericB;
```

En el main probaremos ingresando valores ya sea de tipo numerico o cadena.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Double a=1.0;
    Float  b=0.5F ;     
    comparar(a,b );
}


public static <T> void comparar(T a, T b) {
                    
    try {       
        String typeA= getType(a,"A");
        String typeB= getType(b,"B");
        
        if (typeA.equals("")) {
            System.out.println("A no es objeto de tipo numerico por lo tanto no se puede hacer la operacion = " + a);
            
        }else if (typeB.equals("")) {
            System.out.println("B no es objeto de tipo numerico por lo tanto no se puede hacer la operacion = " + a);
            
        }else { 
            if (genericA > genericB) {
                System.out.println("a es mayor" + a);
            } else {
                System.out.println("b es mayor" + b);
            }
        }
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("No se puede comparar" + e);
    }
}
```

usaremos un metodo llamado getType para saber que tipo de dato es el ingresado y poder asignar valor correspondiente.

```
private static String getType(Object o, String type) {      

    if(o instanceof Integer) {
        if(type.equals("A")) {
            genericA= Double.valueOf((Integer) o);              
        }else {
            genericB= Double.valueOf((Integer) o);
        }
        return "Integer";
    }
    
    if(o instanceof Long) {
        if(type.equals("A")) {
            genericA= Double.valueOf((Long) o);                 
        }else {
            genericB= Double.valueOf((Long) o);
        }   
        return "Long";
    }

    if(o instanceof Double) {
        if(type.equals("A")) {
            genericA= (Double) o;               
        }else {
            genericB= (Double) o;
        }
        return "Double";
    }

    if(o instanceof Float) {
        if(type.equals("A")) {
            genericA= Double.valueOf((Float) o);                
        }else {
            genericB= Double.valueOf((Float) o);
        }
        return "Float";
    }
    
    if(o instanceof BigDecimal) {
        if(type.equals("A")) {
            genericA= ((BigDecimal) o).doubleValue();               
        }else {
            genericB= ((BigDecimal) o).doubleValue();
        }
        return "BigDecimal";
    }
    
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo usaría el concepto de [***bounded type parameters***](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) (parámetro de tipo acotado), que permite restringir el tipo de dato que podemos usar como tipo del genérico (el tipo de dato del que podrá ser `T`), junto con la interfaz [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) para indicar que el método `comparar()` solo puede ser llamado con tipos de datos comparables.

```
public static <T extends Comparable> void comparar(T a, T b){
    int result = a.compareTo(b);
    if (result > 0) {
        System.out.println("a es mayor que b");
    } else if (result < 0) {
        System.out.println("a es menor que b");
    }

    System.out.println("a y b son iguales");
}
```